# C# client socket for synchronous

Tags: c#, sockets, synchronous

I have a 3Rd party server where I send it data and then wait for a response.

It will first respond with ack then with the full response

I am doing something like this. Is there a better way.

```
//Connect
eftSocket.Connect(remoteEp);

// Encode the data string into a byte array.
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strRequest);


// Send the data through the socket.
int bytesSent = eftSocket.Send(msg);

//receive first time
int bytesRec = eftSocket.Receive(bytes);

//Do we get an ack,
if (bytes[0] != 6)
{
    throw new Exception("Could not connect to EFT terminal");
}

//receive 2nd time
bytesRec = eftSocket.Receive(bytes);
```

Comment: You are doing it the correct method.  But there is still an issue if the data doesn't all come at the same time.  It is possible with TCP for messages to be broken up randomly and the recombined.  So with ascii data I always send an '\n' after each message and wait for the return before continuing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for this.

Comment: One more thing. I have noticed that at the point of checking for an ack I sometimes get zero bytes. I have read that this is when the connection is lossed. Some people say to put a sleep (500) before receive. I haven't tried this yet, but do you know what could cause this.

Comment: TCP use empty data packet as a keepalive.  The client normally sends this to server so server doesn't close connection when channel is idle.  So you can ignore empty packets.  That is another reason for have a termination of each message so you know when a message really ends.  There should be no reason to add waits if the code is written correctly.  I think is is silly to add a wait it is better to just ignore the empty packets.  I prefer to use asyn method.

Comment: How would I ignore this when using synchronous.  Some kind of while loop?

Comment: Yes you can use a while.

Comment: Could It be the case I end up in an endless loop.

Comment: Never if the code is correct and the server is working properly.  Have you considered the case if the server is turned off while you code is running or you send an invalid command?  The only time you end up in an endless loop if you don't send the server a command but end up waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks broken. At first you have to embrace that TCP is a stream and that there are no packets. That means even if the client sends something of a given length you can never expect that you receive it in one turn. Which means if you do `eftSocket.Receive(bytes)` you might receive any amount of bytes which were sent from the remote, not necessarily the ack byte in the first call and the remaining stuff in a second call. The only thing that you know is that you won't receive more than `bytes.Length` with it. If you hand it over a significantly large buffer you might receive everything (ACK + remaining data) in one turn. Therefore you should always check the return value first. And if you expect more bytes repeat the Receive calls with the required offsets.

Then you should at first check whether your receive suceeded at all. You might receive 0, which means the remote closed the socket. If that's the case `bytes[0]` will yield anything which was stored in it before the Receive started.

You should also properly close your socket. It's not obvious from the code example if it happens, but if you return from the code with an Exception it might be missing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks guys. This is a great help.